# JHipster monolithic build production fail

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I have a monolithic JHipster application. I've already disabled `"serviceDiscoveryType"` to `false` in `.yo-rc.json` but 
when I execute the following command

```
./mvnw -Pprod
```

I receive this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:138)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:97)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:621)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:365)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
        at br.com.pactoebytes.GestaoFranquiasApp.main(GestaoFranquiasApp.java:65)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/config/GestaoFranquias/prod/master": Connection refused: connect; nested
e
```

Is it a bug or a configuration issue?

Comment: So you disabled discovery but did you re-generate your project after? If not your bootstrap.yml still configures it.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou yeah I re-generate the project and bootstrap.yml was overwritten. Do I need change something in bootstrap.yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you probably don't need a `bootstrap.yml` as you don't use service discovery nor Spring Cloud config server (i.e. JHipster registry), so your app should only require `application*.yml`.

Try to remove any `bootstrap*.yml` files.

Project re-generation does not take care of removing unneeded files.

Comment: Just do I need delete bootstrap files or also re-generate?

Comment: Just delete bootstrap files

Comment: Why when I start the application using `-Pprod` it doesn't start the production database?

Comment: That's the normal behavior, you are responsible for starting up your database either as a docker container or as a server somewhere. And of course, you won't use maven for starting your app in production

Comment: I started the postgres database in my machine and I updated the datasource properties in application-prod but it keep connecting to h2 database

Comment: Please start a new question with more details